# In Windows OS where does the Virtual memory address table that maps to Physical memory reside?

Tags: virtualization, memory

I'm not asking about the page file.

I just started reading windows internals, and the writer isn't clear in where the page table is in the first chapter, maybe later in the virtual memory chapter it will become clear and I didn't want to skip chapters to get this answer. I like understanding what I read as I go on. I researched on google and didn't find any clear answers either, at least not from the articles/posts I read.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I copied this question to SuperUser, I just signed up for this site so wasn't aware of how things work.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is called the [*page table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table), and it is stored in kernel memory.

Comment: Correct. And the page table is loaded/stored into RAM at bootup?

Comment: No. The page table is created in memory as needed -- there's nothing to load.